# No se crea la base de datos usando entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Basicamente seguí todos los pasos según tengo entendido como pueden ver este es el DBContext que tengo creado.

```
namespace MODELO
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Ouroboros : DbContext
    {
        public static Ouroboros instancia;
        public static Ouroboros OBTENER_INSTANCIA()
        {
            if (instancia == null)
            {
                instancia = new Ouroboros();
            }
            return instancia;
        }
        public Ouroboros()
            : base("name=Ouroboros")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Check_lists_PVR> Check_Lists_PVR { get; set; }
    }
```

Estas son las propiedades de objeto en cuestión que estoy tratando de guardar.

```
namespace MODELO
{
    [Table("Check_lists_PVR")]
    public class Check_lists_PVR
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 NroCL { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Turno { get; set; }
        public string PVR { get; set; }
        public string Operador { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public string Observacion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo todas las funciones que programe en "controladora" para agregar, modificar, eliminar, etc.

```
namespace CONTROLADORA
{
    public class CHECK_LISTS_PVR
    {
        public static CHECK_LISTS_PVR instancia;
        public static CHECK_LISTS_PVR OBTENER_INSTANCIA()
        {
            if (instancia == null)
            {
                instancia = new CHECK_LISTS_PVR();
            }
            return instancia;
        }
        MODELO.Ouroboros oOuroboros;
        public CHECK_LISTS_PVR()
        {
            oOuroboros = MODELO.Ouroboros.OBTENER_INSTANCIA();
        }
        public void Agregar_CHKlist(MODELO.Check_lists_PVR oCHKPVR)
        {
            oOuroboros.Check_Lists_PVR.Add(oCHKPVR);
            oOuroboros.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Modificar(MODELO.Check_lists_PVR oCHKPVR)
        {
            oOuroboros.Entry(oCHKPVR).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            oOuroboros.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Eliminar(MODELO.Check_lists_PVR oCHKPVR)
        {
            oOuroboros.Check_Lists_PVR.Remove(oCHKPVR);
            oOuroboros.SaveChanges();
        }
        public List<MODELO.Check_lists_PVR> Listar_CHKlists()
        {
            return oOuroboros.Check_Lists_PVR.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Tras mucho ir y venir habilite todas las migraciones, actualice la base de datos, inicio el programa, cargo los datos y cuando doy a guardar el programa no rompe ni arroja errores, sigue los procesos con total normalidad. pero a la hora de ir a revisar en sql management que todo este correcto la base de datos no existe. Alguien que haya pasado por lo mismo que me pueda dar una mano?

Comment: Hola @Todema. A la hora de hacer una pregunta es mejor que pongas el código que imágenes porque así podemos copiarlo y probarlo más facilmente y también, puede ser se caduquen esos links y que la pregunta quede vacía.

Comment: Si si es que justo estaba de salida del trabajo por eso puse las imagenes. Prometo que apenas llego edito y pongo codigo